# setup routine for checking host os

Tags: linux, shell

I would like to write a small setup script for a program. So i would like to prepare some things related to the target os.

Actually i'm using:

```
sascha@sascha-desktop:/etc$ cat *release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=15.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=vivid
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 15.04"
cat: make-test-release: Ist ein Verzeichnis
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="15.04 (Vivid Vervet)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 15.04"
VERSION_ID="15.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

Maybe you can give me the output in case of a Fedora, RedHat, Debian and openSUSE case?
Or exists a better solution for that?

Comment: Many more recent distributions include a program called `lsb_release` that will provide some of that information. But older releases, and those that do not claim LSB compliance may not...

Comment: But even for those that do, many return `LSB Version:    n/a`. Which is of dubious helpfulness. `uname -om` can provide **OS** and **architecture**. (you can check `uname -a` to see all available output. Be wary of using `/etc/*release`, the contents can change from release to release in the same distro, and there is no consistency of contents across distros.